# Bootstrap collapse vertical toggle switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
$('#demo').on('hidden', function () {
    $('#divbody').removeClass('span4').addClass('span8');
});
```

When the `button` is clicked: the `demo` div collapses vertically (i.e. width = 0) which works fine. But I want to then increase the `divbody` div to fill the page i.e. `span8`. The JS code is there but I want to do it animation like when the `demo` div collapses.

Comment: Can you add the jsFiddle please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TFHXY/ - I have added the fiddle, thanks

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly the problem, sorry.. Maybe a real example on other website to illustrate it?

Comment: Donovan as per the code above: I have 2 divs: the main body and sidebar (demo). what I want is the sidebar div to be collapsable width=0 which works BUT at the same time I want the main body div width to increase to double its width size. At this point the button label will change to show. And once clicked on the width of both sidebar and body will revert back as original was. all in animation. I have managed to get it working for the sidebar to collapse width=0 and increase span of body div to 8 but this is not animated like how the div collapses. hope this is clear

Comment: And what is your bootstrap version? Because I don't arrive to find span1,span2 ... span8 in the bootstrap.min.css. It's the version 3.0?

Comment: Sorry my CSS version is: Bootstrap v2.3.2

Comment: Sorry my CSS version is: Bootstrap v2.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this should help you get an idea, I did not have a whole lot to go off of on your fiddle.  But this should get you started.

jQuery

```
$('#hideBtn').click(function(){
   $('#divbody').toggleClass('span4');
   $('#divbody').toggleClass('span8');
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('span2');
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('span1');
});
```

CSS

```
#divbody {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.35s ease;
  transition: width 0.35s ease;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
        <button role="button" id="hideBtn" class="btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"> Hide </button>    
        <div id="demo" class="collapse in width">
            <div style="width: 400px;">
                <p> This should collapse vertical (by width)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divbody" class="span4">
       Table comes here. This is the main body. Span should increase from 4 to 8 when div demo is collapsed. test test test test test test test test test test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example

http://www.bootply.com/90126

Another example with the button below instead of to the side..

http://www.bootply.com/90128